# transfer DATA between Excel worksheets without sending the actual worksheet template

Tags: excel, powershell, automation, etl

How can I transfer DATA between Excel worksheets without sending the actual worksheet template?

The source is `.xls`; the desination is `.xlsm`.

I have a powershell script that transfers a **worksheet** from the source to the destination and does some renaming to make it **appear** to the end-user as though only the data is transfered, but in reality, it is copying the worksheet into the destination file, then renaming the original worksheet, then renaming the copied worksheet to take the place of the original, then deleting the now-renamed-but-original worksheet.

This is a problem because some cells in the workbook refer to the original worksheet (which gets renamed and then deleted), so the reference breaks and turns into `#REF!`.

Is there a way to simply transfer the **contents** of the source worksheet into the empty destination worksheet, without having to actually copy/rename the worksheets?

If not, how can I keep my script but make sure the references in Excel do not get broken?

In case you are curious to see my script as it works currently, here it is:

```
$file1 = $args[0]

$file2 = $args[1]

    <#
        $file1 = 'c:\source.xls' # source's fullpath
        $file2 = 'c:\destination.xlsm' # destination's fullpath
    #>

    $xl = new-object -c excel.application
    $xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user

    $wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
    $wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
    $sh2_wb2 = $wb2.sheets.item('SheetOfInterest') # sheet in destination workbook
    $sheetToCopy = $wb1.sheets.item('SheetOfInterest') # source sheet to copy

    $sh2_wb2.Name = "OldSheetOfInterest" #Rename original sheet in template
    $sheetToCopy.copy($sh2_wb2)  # copy source sheet to destination workbook

    $sh2_wb2 = $wb2.sheets | where {$_.name -eq "OldSheetOfInterest"}
    $sh2_wb2.delete() #Delete original sheet in template

    $wb1.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
    $wb2.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
    $xl.quit()
    spps -n excel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$file1 = $args[0]

$file2 = $args[1]

    <#
        $file1 = 'c:\source.xls' # source's fullpath
        $file2 = 'c:\destination.xlsm' # destination's fullpath
    #>

$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user

$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
$destination = $wb2.sheets.item('SheetOfInterest') # sheet in destination workbook
$source = $wb1.sheets.item('SheetOfInterest') # source sheet to copy

[void]$destination.UsedRange.Clear() # Clear cells that have data in the destination
[void]$source.UsedRange.Copy() # Copy range of cells with data in them on source sheet
[void]$destination.Range("A1","A1").Select() # Set first cell of destination as active cell
[void]$destination.paste() # Paste data into destination sheet starting at active cell (A1)
[void]$destination.Range("A1","A1").Select() # Set first cell of destination as active cell, otherwise is has everything selected

$wb1.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb2.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```